# Folder with dots not being added in git commit

Tags: git, github

I have a folder inside my repository that has the following name `test.1.2.3`. However, I'm unable to add the folder to my git commit. If I change the name to `test-1-2-3` it works as expected and the folder is added to the git commit.

If I add the folder to the repo and run `git add .;git commit -m "change made"` the command returns:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

It seems that by having dots inside my folder name git is unable to add it to the repository. What's causing this and how can I properly add the folder to the git commit? At this time it is impossible for me to remove the dots from the folder name.

Comment: Could it be your project or global `.gitignore` which contains a matching pattern?

Comment: It likely is. See my comment in the approved answer. I believe there is something else at play that goes beyond this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git generally doesn't like having dots in directories. The easiest (in terms of my understanding) fix is to go into your .gitignore and add the directory names to the list, but negate them:

```
!test.1.2.3/*
```

I'm unsure of a solution that works for all directories with dots but this will work if you add them 1 by 1.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I tested this in a separate test repo and it works. However, for an unknown reason applying this rule to the .gitignore still does not fix my issue. I have to suspect that there is something else at play. For now I will accept this answer because my issue is goes beyond the question at hand.